# Sqlite statement "DELETE FROM <table_name> IF EXISTS <table_name>" keeps getting syntax error near "IF"

Tags: sqlite

This statement is for a C funciton that create(or open) a table (called SensorData)in the sql database. It's supposed to clear all the data in the table if the table already exists. The statement,

```
DELETE FROM SensorData IF EXISTS SensorData;
```

keeps getting syntax error near `IF`. Anyone got any idea what the syntax error is? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: In SQL you filter rows with `WHERE`, not `IF`.

Comment: And `EXISTS` needs to be followed by a subquery.

Comment: You'll have to update your application to query whether the table exists first, and if it does, then delete from it.

Comment: The command to clear all the data in a table is `TRUNCATE TABLE SensorData`.

Comment: @Barmar Not in sqlite it isn't.

Comment: @Shawn You're right. I got lots of hits when I googled "sqlite truncate table", but I never actually looked at them to see that they said it doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use :
Delete from sensorData if you don't want to loose the indexes values for autoincrement indexes.
You Can drop the table and recreate it table.

Comment: Truncate is not a sqlite SQL statement...